# Why printf() shows variable's memory adress intead variables's number

Tags: c, calculator, calculation

I made a calculator in C. However, the result shows a false number for some reason. Instead, it produces some random numbers. This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char operator;
    long long num1;
    long long num2;
    long long result;
    //Asks user to input operator
    printf("Please choose operator:");
    scanf("%c", &operator);
    //Asks user to input first number
    printf("Please enter first number:");
    scanf("%lld", &num1);
    //Asks user to input second number
    printf("Please enter second number:");
    scanf("%lld", &num2);
    switch(operator)
    {
        case 'a':
            result = num1 + num2;
            printf("%lld", &result);
            break;
        case 's':
            result = num1 - num2;
            printf("%lld", &result);
            break;
        case 'm':
            result = num1 * num2;
            printf("%lld", &result);
            break;
        case 'd':
            result = num1 / num2;
            printf("%lld", &result);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid operator");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example:

Please choose operator:a (add operator)

Please enter first number:5 (first number is 5)

Please enter second number:3 (second number is 3)

27583894889037472 (but it doesnt't display 8)

Instead, add 3 to 5 and display 8, this produces an wrong result.

Comment: Do not ignore scanf return values. The will help you understand most problems with scanf. (Though in this case see below comment.)

Comment: Remove the `&` from the arguments to `printf`. They are only required for `scanf` ... in output, that means you are printing the addresses of the arguments, not their  values.

Comment: What does your text book tell you about `printf` and the arguments to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the output like this

```
printf("%lld", result);
```

The & means "Don't take the variable, take the place in memory where this variable is stored.

Comment: I propose rephrasing, it might puzzle inexperienced programmers what the difference between the variable and the place in memory is. Maybe something like "numerical value of its address in memory".